# Where can I find articles about Handley Page multi element segmented airfoils?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

Can anyone direct me to a source containing the complete article on Handley Page's [6 and 8 element airfoils](http://adg.stanford.edu/aa241/highlift/images/image236.gif) from [Flight magazine Feb 24, 1921 <sup>(PDF)</sup>](https://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1921/1921%20-%200130.PDF) or further more detailed information on this subject.

Comment: Flight magazine Feb 1921 is [here](https://archive.org/details/sim_flight-international_1921-02-24_13_8/page/132/mode/2up).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The images look a lot like the ones in:

[A.M.O. Smith, “High-Lift Aerodynamics”, 37th Wright Brothers Lecture, Journal of Aircraft, Vol. 12, No. 6, June 1975](https://charles-oneill.com/aem614/ReferenceMaterial/A+M+O+Smith+HIGH+LIFT+AERODYNAMICS.pdf)

The  classic paper on multi element airfoils, great read!

Comment: Ye link breaketh.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, it should be active again.