# What is the effect of airflow speed on separation?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, wing

[image: picture of flow over an airfoil]
We know that in real viscous flow, boundary layer exists around the airfoil and there will be a separation point which flow starts to separate from the back of the airfoil( velocity gradient equal zero at separation point). If the flow speed increases, will separation occur earlier or later?

Comment: Is this a homework question of some sort, or otherwise assigned to you?

Comment: @RalphJ Nope just curious about it

Comment: @mins yeah that's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a subsonic flow, the separation point moves downstream as [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) increases, and Reynolds number increases with free stream velocity.

Demonstration on a cylinder-shaped airfoil:

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S004579301630202X)</sup>

---

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number):

> Reynolds number is the ratio of inertial forces to viscous forces
>   within a fluid which is subjected to relative internal movement due to
>   different fluid velocities

Separation occurs at the location the laminar airflow stops being accelerated, and is decelerated by areas of upstream turbulent airflow in separation bubbles created by friction (viscosity):

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://www.southampton.ac.uk/engineering/research/projects/aerofoil_separation_bubbles.page)</sup>

Velocity gradients in the boundary layer at different points in the transition area where the flow transitions from laminar to turbulent:

[image]  
<sup>[Source](https://slideplayer.com/slide/716796/), adapted</sup>

Velocity is decreasing near the surface due to friction, and at some point becomes negative. Separation bubbles appear between the laminar flow and the airfoil. In a bubble there is a secondary reverse flow and a region where air is stagnant. Downstream the bubble, air is turbulent:

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/501/1/012024/pdf), adapted</sup>

While other elements affect the boundary layer separation point, this one is the largest. To counter this effect, the momentum of the laminar stream must be increased relatively to frictional forces. This is done (by definition) by increasing the Reynolds number, e.g. by increasing the airspeed.

Increasing airspeed can be obtained by accelerating the aircraft, but also by other ways. For example, different devices are used to delay the separation of the boundary layer when the aircraft must be slowed down. It consists on accelerating ("re-energizing") "dead air" near the surface, e.g. using high speed jets or vortex generators.

This is for instance the principle behind slats and slotted flaps:

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://fugahumana.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/high-lift-devices/), adapted</sup>

---

The boundary layer separation is due to flow deceleration as it moves away from the leading edge and an [adverse pressure gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_pressure_gradient) appears ([potential flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow) theory).

The lower energy flow is more prone to perturbations, vortexes appear and disappear, increasing in importance. Portions of vortexes have a velocity opposed to the free stream velocity, this creates areas of "dead air". Viscosity takes over inertia. This ratio between inertia and viscosity effects is the very definition of the Reynolds number.

By increasing velocity (actually the Reynolds number), this effect is minimized: The separation point moves downstream, as the effects of the adverse pressure gradient are countered on a longer distance as visible on the velocity gradients shown on the flap/slat picture above.

Flaps/slats have the additional advantage (over vortex generators for instance) of increasing the wing surface, hence restoring lift lost when the airplane was slowed down.

Comment: Thank u very much. This answer is exactly what I want. Initially, I thought in this way: higher speed means more time to decelerate the velocity gradient to 0( where separation occurs). So the separation point moves downwards. It seems too simple to be wrong. Could u explain more about why separation point move downward and why related to Reynolds number directly?

Comment: @HanzhiZhang: At higher speed the air molecules come with more inertial energy, but viscosity has not changed. This means more "oomph" is available to be eaten up in friction before the air comes to a standstill relative to the wing.

Comment: @PeterKämpf thanks I understand it 

Comment: What a wonderful answer!

Comment: @PeterKämpf,what is "oomph" ?

Comment: @mins,isnt flow separation happend because of adwerse pressure gradient not friciton(viscosity)?

Comment: @AeronauticFreek Without the slowing down from friction the adverse pressure gradient would not be enough to bring the air to a complete stop. Friction is essential because it robs the boundary layer of energy which is then missing when the pressure gradient adds another deceleration.

Comment: @AeronauticFreek: Friction at the wing interface, propagated partially to the whole boundary layer by air viscosity, creates a continuous decrease of airspeed along the chord, hence a deceleration of the flow. In the boundary layer, along the chord and at any height, there is a continuous increase of static pressure, and a decrease of dynamic pressure. This variation of static pressure along the chord is the gradient (∇ variation). So everything starts with the initial friction on the wing, low velocity will be seen in the inner boundary layer, and in the rest of the layer, at some degree.

Comment: @mins,@PeterKampf, are you also members at physicsforum? my opinion is that stackechange have great people for aerodynamics,but here is forbiden  to comment to much like on real forum,so what are your suggestion where is best forum for aerodynmics where we can deeply talk?

Comment: @AeronauticFreek: You need to use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=aviation.stackexchange.com) (Hangar for broadcast)