# How does more lift help during a stall (ex. flaps deployed)

Tags: aerodynamics

How does more lift help in a stall? For flaps, I thought the effective increase in camber of the wing would make the wing have a higher AoA, therefore making a stall happen sooner.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48100/why-does-stall-speed-decrease-when-flaps-are-deployed? Also, by "sooner", do you mean at a lower nose-up *fuselage angle* in relation to the flight path / relative wind, or do you mean at a higher *airspeed*? Your question suggests some possible confusion between the two. Just because you change the wing shape in a way that would increase wing's aoa *if for some reason the fuselage angle in relation to the flight path stayed constant*, doesn't mean that you are increasing the wing a-o-a associated with *any given airspd*.

Comment: @quiet flyer Ah okay, thanks for the link!

Comment: In addition of the linked question elements: Flaps (and slats) [re-energize the boundary layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cujwe.png), moving the separation bubbles aft, causing the flow to reattach. See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/60453/3201) for details about the origin of the separation bubbles.