# Why aren't compressor and turbine blades flat?

Tags: engine, turbofan, turbine, compressor

Why are the compressor and turbine blades of a jet engine shaped as airfoils?  Why can't they be flat?

Comment: Related: [What is the performance of a flat plate wing?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21391/1696)

Comment: @CarloFelicione that question is about changes along the length of fan blades, this one is about the profile of turbine and compressor blades. Different parts and different properties.

Comment: Guten Tag, Manfred - would you mind to spell your [name](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manfred_von_Richthofen) correctly?