# How to approximate the drag for rectangular vertical flat panel placed along the wind and inclined?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, drag

[image: on the top is view from the top]

So on the top is the view from the top, below it is the side view.

If the angle is zero it is similar to simple flat airfoil.
So I calculated the Cl and Cd in xfoil and
got the Cl = 0 and Cd = 0.02398 :

[image: flat panel in xfoil]

It is for 30 cm length in 5 m/s stream

Cl will be directed to the viewer, perpendicular to the panel.

Was it a correct application of xfoil ?

How to approximate the Cd also for non-zero angles like 1 ~ 15 ?

Will it be "almost the same" so the difference can be ignored ?

At non zero angle the plane of the plate will continue to be parallel to the wind but its geometry becomes more complex, similar to swept wing.

Comment: I'd simply decompose $V_{wind}$ in its two components parallel and perpendicular to the plate and calculate the two relevant $C_d$s

Comment: @sophit Do you know some book or article describing this decomposition approach ?

Comment: ? This is basic phisics/trigonometry: your velocity can be decomposed as the sum of two mutually perpendicular velocities, one parallel to the length of the plate and with a value $V_{wind}cos(\alpha)$ and one perpendicular to it with value $V_{wind}sin(\alpha)$. Each one of these two speed generates a relevant drag term, one parallel and one perpendicular, which you can afterward combine in one single term.

Comment: Related question and answers [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21391/what-is-the-performance-of-a-flat-plate-wing).

Comment: @sophit I use V when I calculate the Re to get the Cd and when I calculate the q ( dynamic pressure ). Should I decompose V in both cases ?

Comment: @Robert DiGiovanni  It is not a wing , it is more like stabilizer because it is in the vertical plane , parallel to the wind direction