# What are some features of a wing, which effects its lift coefficient other than its sectional view?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, lift, stall

What geometrical features of a lifting surface apart from which airfoil it has, I mean the ones visible from the top and front view of a wing (for ex: its span, AR, sweep, dihedral etc.) effects its lift coefficient and **in what way**? Also its stall characteristics.

I'm not looking for how these features change the total lift a wing produces but its effects on the wings lift coefficient, please correct me if I'm wrong and Cl is only for airfoils.

Edit: I ve found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xn3m.png) which explains AR and sweep but how dihedral, anhedral or any other wing modification effects Cl still remains as a question.

Comment: Try looking for some equations containing those parameters and see what they each do and what they don’t do.

Comment: i couldnt find those equations

Comment: @TimothyScherer Try [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14508/what-is-the-method-to-calculate-a-finite-wings-lift-from-its-sectional-airfoil/14559#14559)

Answer (score 1):

Anhedral and dihedral have an effect by causing the vector of lift to be at a slight angle, inward (dihedral) or outward (anhedral). This would also have an effect on induced drag, as do winglets. As far as stalling characteristics go, it is complex enough that it may be best to model it on computer.