# How does a diffuser (in ground effect) accelerate the air in front of it?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-dynamics

A diffuser reduces speed and increases pressure, so how does a diffuser accelerate air in front of it if we have an **adverse pressure gradient situation**?

Wouldn't be better that we put the lower pressure (instead of higher) on end which will "pull"/accelerate air in front of it?

Example of F1 diffuser in ground effect:

[image]

Comment: Where is the diffusor? The question is unclear.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, at rear  floor on F1 car,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMojq8Qj5MY..

Comment: @PeterKämpf,is it possible that nobody at physics site and aviation site dont know answer?

Comment: Would [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/why-the-ground-effect-has-such-a-different-outcome-for-wings-and-cars) and its answers help?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this isn’t strictly an aviation question, it does involve aerodynamic principles.

To put it simply, the diffuser’s main purpose is to gradualize the transition from rapidly flowing air under the car’s body as it transitions back to the speed of the ambient air behind the car.

There is a high pressure zone in front of the car from air particles colliding with the vehicle, and a low pressure zone in the wake behind the car as airflow is attempting to rejoin on the other side. This high to low flow draws air under the car where space is limited. This limited space results in an increase in speed and a decrease pressure, thus increasing downforce as the pressure below the car is less than the pressure on the top and sides of the car. This is Bernoulli’s equation at work.

However, the rapidly moving air experiences adverse pressure gradient at the rear of the car and airflow separation results in significant turbulence. This turbulence not only increases drag, but limits how quickly air can be evacuated from underneath the car. By carefully shaping a diffuser, the airflow can be slowed more gradually, easing its transition back into the ambient flow, minimizing turbulence which increases the flow speed under the car, decreasing the pressure and increasing downforce on the wheels even further.

The diffuser is shaped to increase the airflow speed in front of this funnel to ‘push’ a low pressure zone in front of the funnel, more effectively drawing air into the diffuser.

Comment: ,,,wouldn be better to put wing low pressure side on the end of floor,so low pressure from wing will "suck/accelarate air  under floor,so in this case we dont have adverse pressure gradient-situation?

Comment: The low pressure side IS under the car, where the strakes begin and air is accelerated into the front of the diffuser. The diagram you have up there isn’t precise to scale, it just shows the general region that the adverse pressure gradient begins. It can’t be avoided altogether. The airflow is going to separate from the underside surface. It’s just a matter of making that transition as smooth as possible. There are wind tunnel videos you can look up that use smoke to show the difference in turbulence with and without a diffuser.

Comment: is pressure in diffuser lower than atmosferic pressure?

Comment: Pressure in a diffuser is in transition from much-lower-than-ambient-atmospheric-pressure to a pressure that matches the low-pressure zone in the wake of the car, which is still lower than ambient, but higher than the flow underneath the vehicle.

Comment: ,So diffuser itself produce significiant downforce because his average pressure is lower than ambient pressure?

Comment: The diffuser allows the pressure under the entire car to be lower by increasing the efficient evacuation of airflow. Put simply: the air particles passing through the diffuser do a better job of getting out of the way so that they don't bunch up and slow down the particles coming behind them. This makes air flow faster under the entire car, decreasing pressure, which increases the downforce on the entire car, not just at the diffuser itself.

Comment: @AaronHolmes,https://www.f1technical.net/features/22288   looking at floor ,especially car 2019.Almost 90% area od diffuzer itslef is in low pressure(purple color) and 95% of floor is at atmopsheric pressure,so floor do not produce downforce almost nothing.
People usually describe diffuzer that he accelerate air in front of it/under floor,so floor produce downforce...But I dont see this in floor pressure distribution.
Why is that?

Comment: @NoahPrandtl: On the aerodynamic coefficient chart in your link, the 2019/20 models produced -2.06 out of a total -3.75, or 54.9% of total downforce. The 2021 derived less total downforce from the floor, -1.69 out of -3.36, but this low pressure was more evenly distributed across the bottom of the car due to a reshaping of the diffuser. As you can see, the ‘21 diffuser causes a more gradual release of pressure than in previous years. Aggressive strake funneling on the ‘19/‘20 dramatically decreases the pressure at the opening of the diffuser, localizing downforce in the vicinity of the axle.

Comment: @AaronHolmes,I just want to say that downforce  is almost zero at flat floor,as we can see from 2019 model,95% of floor area is at freestream pressure.So it is wrong  to say that diffuzor accelerate  airflow in front of it/under flat floor, and make suction at entire floor panel.There is no suction at flat floor at all,all job is done by diffuser where color is purple=suction.

Comment: @NoahPrandtl: Not at all. Each diffuser can be shaped to create the desired aerodynamic effects within a certain range of variance. In the image of the ‘21 car, you can see the diffuser working in the way I described - facilitating a more uninterrupted flow of air from the front of the car to the back. In the ‘19 and ‘20 car images, you can see the rounded pressure gradient being ‘pushed’ in front of the diffuser Venturi area since airflow is being tightly restricted and accelerated again just in front of the rear axle. This localizes downforce at the axle.

Comment: Here is a good video explanation. https://airshaper.com/videos/what-is-a-car-diffuser/video/9UgacwMJpuk

Comment: @AaronHolmes,http://www.cabrillo.edu/~jwelch/bernoulli/bernoulli.wmv ,   Can you explain why flat plate in this test dont cause low pressure,you can post answer at my topic: "Why high air speed at flat surface dont allways produce low pressure?"